# MVC Controller Actions and ModelState.IsValid what happens

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What happens during a controller method call? Does MVC for every PUBLIC method in your controller evaluate/set ModelState? Does it test EVERY class in the method parameters??

```
public ActionResult Create(Entity myEntity, AnotherEntity, myEntity2)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

If I had a return of int versus ActionResult:

```
public int Create(Entity myEntity, AnotherEntity, myEntity2)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

Would there still be a ModelState with the evaluated classes??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's not the controller. It's the model binder. The responsibility of the model binder is to instantiate the corresponding model given the request values. So the first step is model binding and the second step is validation. The first step is done by the model binder. If there's an error during this step (for example you have attempted to bind an integer field on your model to an input text in which the user entered some arbitrary text), the model binder automatically adds an error to the model state, so once you enter the controller action you could test whether the `ModelState.IsValid`.

If model binding succeeds then you have an instance of the model that is now passed to the corresponding validation framework. So for example if you are using Data Annotations and decorated the model properties with validation attributes, they will be evaluated and once again if there are errors they will automatically be added to the ModelState.

> If I had a return of int versus ActionResult:

You would violate standard conventions in ASP.NET MVC where all controller actions must return ActionResult. But the return type really has nothing to do with model binding of input parameters and validation. The return type could be any of the possible derived classes of ActionResult or a custom one.

So for example if you want to render the HTML representation of your model you return a `ViewResult`. If you want to return the JSON representation of your model you return a `JsonResult`. If you want to return some static string you return a `ContentResult`. If you want to allow the user download a file you return a `FileResult`. And so on.

Comment: I understand it's the model binder.  What I don't get is when is the model binder called and what is it called on.
Does the model binder get automagically get called for every public method in a controller when the method is called?  Or does it only do this for ActionResults?
Does the model binder then look at every class in the methods parameters and sum all the errors into the ModelState

Comment: The model binder is called before your action is invoked. It is the responsibility of the model binder to retrieve all values from the request and instantiate your model and set its properties by parsing the values. Once all this work is done the controller action is invoked and passed the model that was created by the model binder.